# ¿Cómo Setear theme() de ggplot2 a varios gráficos en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, theme

Por ejemplo deseo hacer varios gráficos en `ggplot2`, en donde deseo que los títulos de los gráficos estén en negrita. Pero para esto tendría que especificar que sea negrita en la función `theme()` en cada uno de los plots.

Por ejemplo.

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=año, y=edad))+
geom_col()+
labs(title="Título 1")+
theme(plot.title = element.text(face= "bold"))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=año, y=var1))+
geom_col()+
labs(title="Título 2")+
theme(plot.title = element.text(face= "bold"))

df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=año, y=xax))+
geom_col()+
labs(title="Título 3")+
theme(plot.title = element.text(face= "bold"))
```

Es decir, estoy repitiendo en cada plot: `theme(plot.title = element.text(face= "bold"))`.

¿Hay alguna forma de dejar de hacer esta repetición? Es decir, setear para que todos los gráficos estén en negrita y no estar escribiendo en cada uno de ellos `theme(plot.title = element.text(face= "bold"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) #Es necesario que esté cargada para usar theme_update()
    
theme_update(plot.title = element_text(face= "bold"))  #Para actualizar algún elemento del tema activo. Solo aplica al tema activo por defecto. No funciona si agregas un tema en llamada del g

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "Foo")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el gráfico tiene el título en negrita si lo creamos después de ejecutar la línea con la función `theme_update()`.

Funciona con `ggplot2 3.3.4` y creo que es una funcionalidad que ya tiene años, así que también debería funcionar con versiones anteriores.

Comment: he corrido la sintaxis que indicas. Pero no logro que los plot tengan el título en negrita. Creo que entendí mal. Por favor, podría ser un poco más específico.

Comment: Agregué un poco de detalle, ojalá funcione. Si estuviste haciendo muchas pruebas para solucionarlo quizás valga la pena que reinicies la sesión de R antes de probarlo y que no uses ningún argumento `theme_*` ya que estarías usando otro tema y no el activo que modificaste. En mi compu funciona, quizás si el problema persiste podrías poner el script completo para ver si alguna defición previa/posterior está haciendo un override a este cambio. Suerte!

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias.